# Conditional statements with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a site that gives the user two opportunities to enter their postal code as a search query: there's an input field on the home page and another one in the search results page if they choose to enter a different postal code.

If the postal code they submit through the home page doesn't match any of the postal codes in the database, the user should be redirected back to the home page. But if they enter a new postal code on the search results page, that page should simply reload and display the appropriate error message. I'm not sure how to write a conditional statement to accomplish 
Basically, I need something along these lines:

```
 #search_controller.rb

   if @postal_code.nil?
      flash[:notice] = "Plans available for residents of Ontario or Alberta, only."
     if current_page?(search_path)
      redirect_to search_path
     else
      redirect_to root_path
     end
    else
    .....
```

If I run that code, I get this error in my heroku logs:
`undefined method 'current_page?'`

What is the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The `current_page?` method is only available in the views.

Probably the easiest solution to go with is to render a hidden field in the search form which has the controller name as its value:

```
`<%= hidden_field_tag :source, controller_name %>`
```

Then in your controller you can simply check if the parameter value matches the search controller name:

```
if params[:source] == controller_name
  redirect_to search_path
end
```

Comment: It works! I just had to set it to `redirect_to :back` so it would reload the search queries as well